# Why does a for loop with a semicolon after it still execute?

Tags: javascript

I was having a look at some code a friend did and stumbled across this line which I thought was an error (simplified for example)..

```
for (g = 0; 10 > g; g++); {

    alert(g);
}
```

However it still executes, and alerts "10". Why is this? Is this a purpose built function in javascript?

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RSwfv/)

Comment: `;` ends the loop here, and you get `10` only once, since the loop is already executed. `{}` just creates a code block.

Comment: its alerting you only once right...

Comment: ye thats what I thought.. but remove the for loop and the semicolon and inside the brackets doesn't execute.

Comment: Actually.. update on above, this is because I was reference the g variable which was now not declared in the for statements.. So I think you are correct sir!

Comment: @user1020317 because variable g does not exist.

Comment: If it helps, mentally translate that `;` into `{}`, and it might make more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `g` variable is within the global context, so it is accessible outside of a `for` loop.
The loop did its job, and incremented `g` 10 times. 
Two `{}` indicate a block in JavaScript and won't cause any error.

**Edit**: it is not alerting anything without a `for` loop, because the `g` variable is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

The semi colon actually runs the loop without the {} code block. So your code basically  has 2 parts,

1. update `variable g` to from 0 to 10 in 10 steps,
2. print out `g` (now equals to 10) once.

Answer (score 1):

your for loop runs 10 times but wont alert anything since you have put `;`

that alert you are getting is only once because of that statement outside of for loop

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know this is simply a syntax feature of the language. Basically, javascript ignores that semicolon.

EDIT: Sorry, misread your post. If you mean that you only get alerted once, then you have basically an empty loop executing ten times, then a single block of code containing the alert executing once.

Accolades ({...}) can go around any block of code, independent of constructs such as for-loops.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Javascript doesn't ignore them but they're considered optional.

Comment: JavaScript certainly does _not_ ignore the semicolon. See the other answers.

Comment: Certainly not.  The behaior of the program would be very different without the semicolon.