# node.js for loop: strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop

I am experimenting with node.js and I am having trouble with a simple for loop...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++); {(
    console.log(i))
   }
```

Why do I get

```
5
```

in console? I was expecting to get

```
0,1,2,3,4...
```

Comment: Remove the `;` right after `for` as your code is exactly equivalent to: `for(...) {}; console.log(i);` where the log happens after the loop (with an empty body) has ended (with `i` now set to `5`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a for loop with a semicolon after it still execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464187/why-does-a-for-loop-with-a-semicolon-after-it-still-execute)

Comment: Thanks! that was so silly from myself :P

Answer (score 5):

Because of the `;` at the end of the for. The loop as you have it is treated as a for loop without a statement because of the semi-colon. This is an entirely valid way to use a `for` loop (see [this MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/for#Using_for_without_a_statement)), which is why you wont see any errors. Basically, in your code, the loop is running (and doing nothing other than incrementing the value of `i`) and after the loop runs, you tell it to output the value of i (which is 5, because the loop has completed).

To achieve what you probably want, the loop should look like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to a syntax error being the semi-colon char between the `for` loop ending parenthesis and the curly brace that follows. You also put useless parenthesis.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```